# How to create more than one foreground notification?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, service, android-notifications

Below is a snippet of code in my service class. 
If a user **"joins a team" (operation = 0)** then it create a notification with its designated specifications however if a **user shares their location (operation = 1)** then its supposed to create a separate foreground notification. Instead one just replaces the other.

 I don't know why, they have different ID's just same channel. *I've also tried separating their channel ID, still the same issue*

```
int id = NOTIFICATION_LOCATION;
        int icon = R.drawable.ic_gps_on;
        String message = "Tap to disable location updates";

        if (operation == 0) {
            id = NOTIFICATION_RESPONDER;
            icon = R.drawable.ic_responder_icon;
            message = "Tap to leave the responding team";
        }

        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID_1)
                .setSmallIcon(icon)
                .setContentTitle("Location established")
                .setContentText(message)
                .setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, getBroadcastIntent(operation), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT))
                .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.primaryColor))
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                .setVisibility(VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
                .build();

        startForeground(id, notification);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notification you manipulate with `startForeground()` is meant to be the one "official" notification that corresponds to the foreground service; the one that Android insists you have up at all times the service is running.

It doesn't surprise me that, if you supply a different notification channel ID on a subsequent call to `startForeground()`, it *erases* and *replaces* the original notification. Otherwise, you might end up with multiple foreground notifications for a single service, and things could get confusing.

**Instead, just use `NotificationManager.notify()` to manage any notifications that occur in excess of the original foreground service notification. Use distinct IDs for these extra notifications.**

A good practice is to use a fixed ID for your foreground service notification. You can still change the `Notification` at will; it's just easier to remember which `Notification` is your "official" one, when you have a fixed ID.

You can also manipulate your "official foreground service notification" using `notify()`; you don't have to use `startForeground()`. A call to `startForeground()` is only needed *once*, at the beginning, to associate the service with a specific notification ID.

Comment: Will the extra notifications be killed. Starting from Oreo, my notifications are usually killed after some minutes.

Comment: @DinhQuanTuan Not sure; you may want to ask a separate question.