# Xiaomi phone killing my multiple app notifications after deleting the app from recents, but foreground service can only keep one. What to do?

Tags: android, kotlin, service, push-notification, xiaomi

I am writing a reminder app which has the following use case:

1. The user sets up a reminder for hour A.
2. The user sets up a reminder for hour B.
3. Hour A arrives and the reminder notification pops up. The user does NOT dismiss it.
4. Hour B arrives and the reminder notification pops up. Two notifications are on the status bar at that moment.

Until now, I was using:

```kotlin
notificationManager.notify(
    alarmId,
    Notification.Builder(context, Constants.PRIMARY_CHANNEL_ID)
       .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.idle_1)
       .setCustomContentView(remoteViews)
       .setOngoing(true)
       .setContentIntent(notifyPendingIntent)
       .setAutoCancel(false).build()
)
```

Without a problem, but apparently [Xiaomi kills notifications](https://dontkillmyapp.com/xiaomi) when the app that threw them gets removed from recents. This would be a critical error for all Xiaomi devices using my app; so I tried using a `ForegroundService` and applying [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57976116/xiaomi-devices-are-stopping-foreground-services).

The problem is using a `ForegroundService` is not intended for handling multiple notifications: if two reminders start the service, the most recent reminder notification will kill and replace the earlier one. (As explained in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60350327/how-to-create-more-than-one-foreground-notification)). Can you see the loop I'm trapped in?

My `ForegroundService` is no big deal, it worked perfectly when I tested it but it has the notification replacement thing.

```
override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId)
    // ...
    startForeground(alarmId, notification)
    return START_STICKY
}
```

At the moment I'm completely stuck: am I missing something or should I just ditch the huge market share Xiaomi phones have due to this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: And up we go...!

Comment: hellooooooooooooooooo?

Comment: I think you dont use startForegroundservice when you want to start your notification service

Comment: stuck in the same problem anybody found the solution?

Comment: Still with the same issue. Crappy developer experience from Xiaomi in this aspect.